# Feynman diagrams with no lines crossing

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, graph-theory

What does it mean when we say a feynman diagram has no lines crossing? What are some examples of diagrams with and without lines crossing?

Comment: Look up [planar diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).

Answer (score 0):

By no crossing lines, I shall assume you mean no vertices.

In that case, that means that you have particles just propagating. For example, if you have just one line connecting two points a, and b, then the line represents a particle propagating from a to b, and annihilating at b.

Vertices represented interactions and are the ones that add all the interesting behaviour to a theory.